# Highlight missing mandatory parameter when calling a method in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans

Is there a way to highlight method calls that are missing a mandatory parameter in NetBeans 8.2 with PHP?

Example:

```
class a {
    public function a($param1, $param2) {
        ....
    }
}

$a = new a();

$a->a($param1);
```

In PyCharm when this happens it highlights the line with the message: "Missing mandatory parameter" (or something like that)

Comment: `PyCharm` equivalent for PHP is `PHPStorm`

Comment: I would like to use `NetBeans` instead of other ide